# caches_page em rails 3 não funciona em produção

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cache, deploy

Em desenvolvimento o caches_page funciona normalmente, mas em produção, ele cria o cache e reescreve o cache a cada acesso. Alguem tem idéia de como esse problema pode ser resolvido?

Meu arquivo config/production.rb:

```
AppRuby::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

end
```

Comment: Olá, bem-vindo ao site. Para formatar blcos de código, inicie cada linha com 4 espaços, ou selecione o bloco todo e clique no botão `{}` do editor. Desta vez fiz pra você, mas fica a dica para a próxima.

Comment: Por favor tem como você colocar um exemplo de como está usando o cache.